# Building an SBT project using Maven

Tags: scala, maven, teamcity, sbt

I am trying to bring [SBT](http://www.scala-sbt.org/) into my organization through a side door. We use [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) for our continuous integration system with all projects built using [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/). I am starting to prefer SBT for building Scala and mixed Scala/Java projects, but I will get resistance if I ask our infrastructure group to modify the continuous integration system to support SBT.

I am looking for a way to provide a minimal `pom.xml` file in the root of my project that then invokes SBT to do the actual build. Is there any way to do this, perhaps with a Maven-to-SBT plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a fan of going against infrastructure since I perform a similar role at my current employment.

However what you could do is download the `sbt-launch.jar` and put it in a `build` directory in your Source Control Repository. Then create a `sbt` file inside that `build` folder with the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
SBT_OPTS="-Xms512M -Xmx1536M -Xss1M -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:MaxPermSize=256M"
java $SBT_OPTS -jar `dirname $0`/sbt-launch.jar "$@"
```

Then create a Command Line build step that does the following:

```
sh build/sbt clean compile
```

Which should give you what you want, this assumes however you have the ability to setup your own build steps that would run this custom script.

I haven't tested this and did it based off the [sbt Setup Documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Setup.html#manual-installation)

Hope it helps.